# Eloquent way of filtering on a laravel pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The query below works fine to retrieve all appointments with their associated clients and users.

```
    $appointments = Appointment::with('client', 'user')
    ->where('appointments.business_id', '=', \Auth::user()->business_id )
    ->orderBy('appointments.start', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

What would be the syntax to add the following criteria to select the appointments :

```
where users.id = \Auth::user()->id
```

I thought that adding the following line would work, but it didn't:

```
->where('users.id', '=', \Auth::user()->id )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the users.id column can not be found in the appointments table
you can not perform a direct where clause on it. The whereHas method **allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations for more details.**

```
  $userId = \Auth::user()->id;

  $appointments = Appointment::with('client', 'user')
   ->whereHas('user',function($query) use($userId)
   {
     $query->where('users.id,'=',$userId);

  })
  ->where('appointments.business_id', '=', \Auth::user()->business_id )
  ->orderBy('appointments.start', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the issue, it would be helpful to explain _how_ or _why_ this code works and what is different than what the OP attempted.

Comment: Thanx @Patricus. Have added little explanation. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: @oseintow That excellent, thanks! I added the following line `->whereHas('user',function($q) { $q->where('users.id','=',\Auth::user()->id); })` and works perfectly